# Split products and make a hover effect on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a brochure with products and every product must be clickable. Also, when user hovers on different products they must have a hover effect (so the user can understand that this is a link to this particular product).

I have tried to create a PDF document with Adobe Acrobat DC Pro and put a link over every single product but there isn't any hover effect (at least I can't create a hover effect with this program). 
So I have a feeling that PDF is not an option and it should be done with javascript.

Also, I have managed to find a brochure that is pretty much the same as what I want so you guys can see a live demo on it.

Here is the link -> https://broshura.bg/aiko/aiko-broshura-do-20-10-19-1

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, but I wrote a quick demo that will guide you in the right way. The hover effect is done using css / javascript.

Demo: https://codepen.io/david-somekh/pen/ExxappY

```
<html>
<script>
function OnProduct(x) {
  x.innerHTML = 'Buy me !! ';
}

function OffProduct(x) {
  x.innerHTML = 'Product 1';
}

function OpenProduct()
{
     window.location = "http://www.google.com/";    
}
</script>
<style>
.product{
height:50px;
border:1px solid black;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.product:hover{
background-color:blue;
color:white;
cursor:pointer;

}
</style>
<div onmouseover="OnProduct(this)" onmouseout="OffProduct(this)" onclick="OpenProduct()" class="product">Product 1</div>
<div onmouseover="OnProduct(this)" onmouseout="OffProduct(this)" onclick="OpenProduct()" class="product">Product 1</div>
<div onmouseover="OnProduct(this)" onmouseout="OffProduct(this)" onclick="OpenProduct()" class="product">Product 1</div>
<div onmouseover="OnProduct(this)" onmouseout="OffProduct(this)" onclick="OpenProduct()" class="product">Product 1</div>
<div onmouseover="OnProduct(this)" onmouseout="OffProduct(this)"  onclick="OpenProduct()" class="product">Product 1</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually the problem is very complex because when you generate a new PDF file, for example, you don't have different div's or anchors for every single image. Inspect for example this PDF with DevTools -> http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf.
So the problem is to split every image in different div's and then create a hover effect with css/js.